# php echo modal doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i was trying to do is checking the user have enter any room before if they didnt leave the room they cant enter new room. but now i my modal wont show up. Anything i was doing wrong?

```
if($checkUser==0){

    echo "<script>$('#myModal').modal('show');</script>

        <div class='modal fade' id='myModal' role='dialog'>
            <div class='modal-dialog modal-lg'>
              <div class='modal-content'>
                <div class='modal-body'>
                  <p>You didn't leave previous chatroom</p>
                </div>
                    <div class='modal-footer'>
                        <a href='index.php'>
                            <button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Leave</button>
                         </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>";                                  
}
```

Comment: If the problem is that html never makes it to the page, double check that `$checkUser` really equals `0`. If you _have_ double checked it, triple check it. If the problem lies elsewhere, you haven't given us enough information to make informed suggestions.

Comment: before i was using ajax to load the file to check the condition and the modal work because i was set it as 2sec load once so the modal will be show every 2 sec. This is no i want. So i put the whole condition into my chatroom.php to do this but the modal wont show

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```html
if($checkUser==0){

    echo "<script>$(document).ready(function(){ $('#myModal').modal('show'); });</script>

        <div class='modal fade' id='myModal' role='dialog'>
            <div class='modal-dialog modal-lg'>
              <div class='modal-content'>
                <div class='modal-body'>
                  <p>You didn't leave previous chatroom</p>
                </div>
                    <div class='modal-footer'>
                        <a href='index.php'>
                            <button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Leave</button>
                         </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>";                                  
}
```

Add `$('#myModal').modal('show');` into `$(document).ready();` because at the time when js loaded `#myModel` does not loaded into DOM. Make sure to load Jquery before that